# How to interpret できた

Tags: meaning, interpretation

How can I interpret できた in this paragraph:

> 昨日、リング上でも言いましたが、最高の空間を作って下さった会場のお客様に、感謝しますよ。まあ、最終戦の13日・両国大会に限らず、全大会、素晴らしい雰囲気の中、素晴らしい空間の中で試合が**できた**と思いますし、過去最高の『G1 CLIMAX』だったんじゃないかなとボクは思ってます。
>   Naito ‘I said as much in the ring last night, but I’m honestly grateful for all the fans for the atmosphere they all created in Ryogoku. But that’s not limited to the last match yesterday. This G1 I was able to put on amazing matches in front of amazing audiences every night. I think this was the best G1 Climax of all time.

I don't know if the subject is the public (会場のお客様) that produced the ambience for the matches, or the event itself (全大会) that produced the matches. Or should I interpret できた as "ended" like in:

> The matches ended with a wonderful atmosphere for the whole event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 全大会、素晴らしい雰囲気の中、素晴らしい空間の中で試合ができたと思います

=全大会**において、我々は（or私は）**(素晴らしい雰囲気の中、素晴らしい空間の中で）試合**をすることが**できたと思います

我々は試合ができた＝we were able to play the matches

***I think we were able to play the matches in an awesome atmosphere, in an awesome environment for all the matches, let alone the final match.***

↑This is my literal translation, and the meaning is exactly you mentioned:

> The matches ended with a wonderful atmosphere for the whole event

Hope this helps!